# Random subreddit image to discord.py bot doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, praw

This is my code, and it returns a bunch of errors when I run the '.memri' command. I wanted my discord bot to get a random picture from the "memritvmemes" subreddit. Can anyone tell me what was I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
import praw
import random
import os

from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='the client id',
    client_secret='the client secret',
    user_agent='Memri TV Bot by /u/Hezbolloli')

@client.command()
async def memri(ctx):
    memri_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memritvmemes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memri_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await ctx.send(submission.url)
```

This is my error log in the python shell:

```
Ignoring exception in command memri:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\Desktop\app.py", line 69, in memri
    submission = next(x for x in memri_submissions if not x.stickied)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\Desktop\app.py", line 69, in <genexpr>
    submission = next(x for x in memri_submissions if not x.stickied)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 61, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 71, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 454, in get
    data = self.request("GET", path, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 626, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 183, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 115, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 98, in _make_request
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 35, in call
    kwargs['headers'] = set_header_callback()
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 145, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 299, in refresh
    self._request_token(grant_type='client_credentials')
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 138, in _request_token
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 31, in _post
    raise ResponseException(response)
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response
```

Comment: 401 means unauthorised. Make sure your `praw` is set up correctly. See here: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#read-only-reddit-instances

Comment: @Benjin You are right, I fixed the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet of code:

```
@client.command()
async def memri(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memritvmemes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.hot(limit=50)
    for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title=name)
    em.set_image(url=url)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```